# How could I get an array of emojis found in iOS8.3

Tags: ios, swift, emoji

In iOS 8.3, Apple updated a bunch of emojis, and I am wondering if I could get all of the emojis into an array in a quicker way.

Such as:

```
let emojiArrays = ["","",...] or plist or something else.
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After some struggling,here is the fullest list of emojis found in iOS8.3 written in Swift.Browse in Safari for best compatibility.[April 8 2015]

```
let allEmojis = ["","","","","","","","","","","","","☺️","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","‍‍","‍‍‍","‍‍‍","‍‍‍","‍‍","‍‍","‍‍‍","‍‍‍","‍‍‍","‍‍","‍‍","‍‍‍","‍‍‍","‍‍‍","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","‍❤️‍","‍❤️‍","","‍❤️‍‍","‍❤️‍‍","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","☝","☝","☝","☝","☝","☝","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","✌","✌","✌","✌","✌","✌","","","","","","","✊","✊","✊","✊","✊","✊","✋","✋","✋","✋","✋","✋","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","⚡️","","","☀️","⛅️","☁️","","","☔️","","❄️","","⭐️","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","☕️","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","✨","","","","","","","","","","❤️","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","⛄️","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","⛺️","","⚽️","","","⚾️","","","⛳️","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","️","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","⛽️","","","","","","✈️","","⚓️","","","⛵️","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","⛲️","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","⛪️","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","⌚️","","","","⏰","⏳","⌛️","","","","","","","","☎️","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","✉️","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","✂️","","","","","","","✒️","✏️","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","⛔️","","","","","","","","","","","㊙️","㊗️","","","","","️","","","","","","","","️","","❇️","✳️","❎","✅","✴️","","","","","","","","","","","️","","","","","","","","","♈️","♉️","♊️","♋️","♌️","♍️","♎️","♏️","♐️","♑️","♒️","♓️","","","","","♿️","","","","▶️","◀️","","","⏩","⏪","⏫","⏬","➡️","⬅️","⬆️","⬇️","↗️","↘️","↙️","↖️","↕️","↔️","","↪️","↩️","⤴️","⤵️","","","","#⃣","0⃣","1⃣","2⃣","3⃣","4⃣","5⃣","6⃣","7⃣","8⃣","9⃣","","","","","","ℹ️","","","","➕","➖","〰","➗","✖️","✔️","","™","©","®","","","➰","➿","〽️","❗️","❓","❕","❔","‼️","⁉️","❌","⭕️","","","","","","","","Ⓜ️","⛎","","","","⚠️","♨️","♻️","","","♠️","♣️","♥️","♦️","☑️","⚪️","⚫️","","","","","","","","","","▪️","▫️","⬛️","⬜️","◼️","◻️","◾️","◽️","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]
```

Also you could write them into a plist file for persistence.

```
(allEmojis as NSArray).writeToFile(NSHomeDirectory() + "/emoji.plist", atomically: true)
```

Comment: how did you get this list, is it from SDK or you found on the web?

Comment: I have prepared gist (plist) contains [all emoticons](https://gist.github.com/mohacs/577169dafcb2904638fd) in IOS 9

Comment: @mohacs I didn't understand what is `diversity` for?

Comment: some emoticons comes with ethnically diverse. "","","","","","". Those are not individual emoticons same emoticon + modifiers. Please have a look at this URL. All explained in here. http://unicode.org/reports/tr51/

Comment: Any chance you have this list for 10.1? 

Comment: I know yr not supposed to say just a thanks, but ... THANKS!!!

Answer (score 12):

You can get all emojis from [here](https://github.com/onmyway133/Smile/blob/master/Sources/Emoji.swift)

I wanted to categorize them like iPhone Emoji keyboard, so you may face same situation

```
let smilyAndPeople = ["","","","","","","","","☺️","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","☹️","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","☠️","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","✊","","","","✌️","","","","","","","☝️","✋","","","","","","","","✍️","","","","","","","","","","","","", "","","","","","","","","","‍♀","","","","","‍♀","","‍♀","","‍♀","","‍♀","","️‍♀️","","‍⚕","‍⚕","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍","‍✈","‍✈","‍","‍","‍⚖","‍⚖","","","","","","","","","‍♀","","","‍♂","","‍♂","","‍♂","","‍♂","‍♀","‍♂","‍♀","‍♂","","‍♂","","‍♂","","‍♂","","‍♂","","","","","‍♂","‍♀","","‍♀","","","","","","‍❤️‍","‍❤️‍","","‍❤️‍‍","‍❤️‍‍","","‍‍","‍‍‍","‍‍‍","‍‍‍","‍‍","‍‍","‍‍‍","‍‍‍","‍‍‍","‍‍","‍‍","‍‍‍","‍‍‍","‍‍‍","‍","‍","‍‍","‍‍","‍‍","‍","‍","‍‍","‍‍","‍‍","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","⛑","","","","","","","","","☂️"]

let animalsAndNature = ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","☘️","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","⭐️","","✨","⚡️","","","☄","☀️","","⛅️","","","","☁️","","⛈","","","☃️","⛄️","❄️","","","","","","","","☔️","","","","",""]

let foodAndDrink = [ "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "☕️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "","","","","","","","","","","","",""]

let objects = [ "", "", "⌚", "", "", "", "⌨️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "☎️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "⏱", "⏲", "⏰", "", "⌛️", "⏳", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "⚖️", "", "", "⚒", "", "⛏", "", "⚙️", "⛓", "", "", "", "", "⚔️", "", "", "⚰️", "⚱️", "", "", "", "", "⚗️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "✉️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "✂️", "", "", "✒️", "", "", "", "✏️", "", "", "", "", "", ""]

let flags = [ "️", "", "", "", "️‍", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]

let symbols =  ["❤️","","","","","","","❣️","","","","","","","","","☮️","✝️","☪️","","☸️","✡️","","","☯️","☦️","","⛎","♈️","♉️","♊️","♋️","♌️","♍️","♎️","♏️","♐️","♑️","♒️","♓️","","⚛️","","☢️","☣️","","","","️","","","️","✴️","","","","㊙️","㊗️","","","","","️","️","","","️","","❌","⭕️","","⛔️","","","","","♨️","","","","","","","","❗️","❕","❓","❔","‼️","⁉️","","","〽️","⚠️","","","⚜️","","♻️","✅","️","","❇️","✳️","❎","","","Ⓜ️","","","","","♿️","️","","️","","","","","","","","","","","","","","ℹ️","","","","","","","","","","0️⃣","1️⃣","2️⃣","3️⃣","4️⃣","5️⃣","6️⃣","7️⃣","8️⃣","9️⃣","","","#️⃣","*️⃣","▶️","⏸","⏯","⏹","⏺","⏭","⏮","⏩","⏪","⏫","⏬","◀️","","","➡️","⬅️","⬆️","⬇️","↗️","↘️","↙️","↖️","↕️","↔️","↪️","↩️","⤴️","⤵️","","","","","","","","➕","➖","➗","✖️","","","™️","©️","®️","〰️","➰","➿","","","","","","✔️","☑️","","⚪️","⚫️","","","","","","","","","","","▪️","▫️","◾️","◽️","◼️","◻️","⬛️","⬜️","","","","","","","","","‍","","","","♠️","♣️","♥️","♦️","","","️","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]

let travelAndPlaces = [ "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "✈️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "⛵️", "", "", "", "⛴", "", "⚓️", "", "⛽️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "⛲️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "⛱", "", "", "⛰", "", "", "", "", "", "⛺️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "⛪️", "", "", "", "⛩", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "","","","",""]

let activity = [ "⚽️", "", "", "⚾️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "⛳️", "", "", "", "", "⛸", "", "⛷", "", "️‍♀️", "", "", "‍♀", "‍♂", "‍♀", "‍♂", "⛹️‍♀️", "⛹", "‍♀", "‍♂", "️‍♀️", "", "‍♀", "", "‍♀", "", "‍♀", "‍♂", "‍♀", "", "", "‍♀", "", "‍♀", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "‍♀", "‍♂", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
```