# How can I display all Apple emojis in a view?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to display all the apple emojis in a view in same sequence as displayed here https://emojipedia.org/apple/ with the help of their unicode.

I used the following code to implement this.

```
let emojiRanges = [
        0x1F601...0x1F64F,
        0x2702...0x27B0,
        0x1F680...0x1F6C0,
        0x1F170...0x1F251
    ]

    for range in emojiRanges {
        for i in range {
            let c = UnicodeScalar(i)
            print(c ?? "")
        }
    }
```

But through this I am not getting expected result. Most of the emojis are missing in between. Please suggest an appropriate solution for this.

Comment: What do you get and what do you expect? What is missing?

Comment: @MartinR : I am getting result like this ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", .....

But I want all emojis in same sequence as displayed here https://emojipedia.org/apple/

Comment: Many emoji characters are the results of combined Unicode characters.

Comment: OT a bit - When you are at it, I suggest you print the screen after you write all the emojis, and show the image instead of the strings... very power efficient...

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60565823/5251783

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0 code...**

```
  let emojiRanges = [
            0x1F601...0x1F64F,
            0x2702...0x27B0,
            0x1F680...0x1F6C0,
            0x1F170...0x1F251
        ]
        var emojiarray:[String] = []
        for range in emojiRanges {
            for i in range {
                let c = String(UnicodeScalar(i)!)
                emojiarray.append(c)
            }
        }
    print(emojiarray)// ["", "", "", "",..............]
```

Comment: You want a  collectionview on uiview and add this emojis

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am getting same result through the code I posted. What I actually require is all the emojis displayed here https://emojipedia.org/apple/  in same sequence. Through above code some emojis are missing like   etc

Comment: @RohitJain you want this emoji in add in the single string then you add a UitextView on UiVew set text on UitextView ...

Comment: That's a pointless solution as many emoji characters are combined results of unicode characters.  Why don't you tell us how you make an emoji named 'family with mother, father and two sonds' with that.

Comment: @ElTomato sir but user want this type