# Replacing code (ex: &#9774;) with emoji in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, api, pinterest, emoji

So, I have a project where I'm grabbing Pinterest pins through the api. I'm able to access everything fine, but when it gets the pinner's description, it replaces emojis as well as some punctuation with codes like the one above, which by looking at the pin on the Pinterest app, I figured out points to a peace sign. When I first saw these, I was just typing up

```
   pinDescription.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&#9774;", withString: "☮")
```

for every single instance. It works as intended, but that's going to be nearly impossible to do for every emoji. I haven't found anything using these kinds of codes while I was searching for a solution, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170876/how-to-list-almost-all-emojis-in-swift-for-ios-8-without-using-any-form-of-loo) is the closest to what I'm looking for here.