# How to get all available emojis in an array in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I want to be able to get an array of all the available emojis in Swift. What I mean by available is all the ones that are current accessable to the device. Like when Apple adds some new emojis, I would like to not have to change any code, and the new emojis just get added in the array with all the other ones.

If getting updated emojis is not possible, then how can I get all of the current emojis into an array (or perhaps a .plist file I can then load into an array) so I can access them in code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This SO seems to provide the answer
[How to list (almost) all emojis in Swift for iOS 8 without using any form of lookup tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170876/how-to-list-almost-all-emojis-in-swift-for-ios-8-without-using-any-form-of-loo)

```
for i in 0x1F601...0x1F64F {  
    let c = String(UnicodeScalar(i) ?? "-")  
    print(c)  
}
```

You should go beyond 1F64F,
[Find out if Character in String is emoji?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757193/find-out-if-character-in-string-is-emoji)

```
        0x1F600...0x1F64F, // Emoticons
        8400...8447: // Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols
        9100...9300, // Misc items
        0x2600...0x26FF,   // Misc symbols
        0x2700...0x27BF,   // Dingbats
        0xFE00...0xFE0F,   // Variation Selectors
        0x1F018...0x1F270, // Various asian characters
        0x1F300...0x1F5FF, // Misc Symbols and Pictographs
        0x1F680...0x1F6FF, // Transport and Map
        0x1F1E6...0x1F1FF, // Regional country flags
        0x1F900...0x1F9FF,  // Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs
        65024...65039, // Variation selector
```

However, you get some undefined (marked as ? at the end of ranges)
See here to skip them
[Is there a way to know if an Emoji is supported in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318999/is-there-a-way-to-know-if-an-emoji-is-supported-in-ios)

Note, while searching, found this interesting link to generate emoji flags based on country code
www.timekl.com/blog/2017/08/31/swift-tricks-emoji-flags/

That ends up with the following code

```
func isEmoji(_ value: Int) -> Bool {  
    switch value {  
    case 0x1F600...0x1F64F, // Emoticons  
    0x1F300...0x1F5FF, // Misc Symbols and Pictographs  
    0x1F680...0x1F6FF, // Transport and Map  
    0x1F1E6...0x1F1FF, // Regional country flags  
    0x2600...0x26FF,   // Misc symbols 9728 - 9983  
    0x2700...0x27BF,   // Dingbats  
    0xFE00...0xFE0F,   // Variation Selectors  
    0x1F900...0x1F9FF,  // Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs 129280 - 129535  
    0x1F018...0x1F270, // Various asian characters           127000...127600  
    65024...65039, // Variation selector  
    9100...9300, // Misc items  
    8400...8447: // Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols  
        return true  

    default: return false  
    }  
}  




extension Character {  
    private static let refUnicodeSize: CGFloat = 8  
    private static let refUnicodePng =  
        Character("\u{1fff}").png(ofSize: Character.refUnicodeSize)  

func png(ofSize fontSize: CGFloat) -> Data? {  
    let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:  
        UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)]  
    let charStr = "\(self)" as NSString  
    let size = charStr.size(withAttributes: attributes)  

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)  
    charStr.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), withAttributes: attributes)  

    var png:Data? = nil  
    if let charImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {  
        png = charImage.pngData()  
    }  

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()  
    return png  
}  

func unicodeAvailable() -> Bool {  
    if let refUnicodePng = Character.refUnicodePng,  
        let myPng = self.png(ofSize: Character.refUnicodeSize) {  
        return refUnicodePng != myPng  
    }  
    return false  
}  
}  

for i in 8400...0x1F9FF where isEmoji(i) {  
    if let scalar = UnicodeScalar(i) {  
        let unicode = Character(scalar)  
        if unicode.unicodeAvailable() {  
            print(i, String(scalar))  
            count += 1  
        } else {  
            notAvail += 1  
            print(i)  
        }  
    } else {  
        notCounted += 1  
    }  
}  

print("Count", count, "Not counted", notCounted, "Not Avail", notAvail)
```